# require_once the same file multiple time?

Tags: php, require

I have a config file that contain credential information to connect to an API

I include my config file in 2 functions in 2 different file

In the first called function, I have my credential variables but when I call my second function, my credential variables are empty.

index.php

```
   <?php
        require_once("./connector/hot/hotelbeds/book.php");

        if($_REQUEST['connector'] == 'hotelbeds')
        {
             require_once("connector/hot/hotelbeds/validate.php");

             validate_hotelbeds($_REQUEST);
        }

        $booking_output = book_hotelbeds($_REQUEST);
    ?>
```

validate.php

```
<?php
    function validate_hotelbeds($results)
    {
        $account = $results['header']['account'];

        include_once("./connector/hot/hotelbeds/account_config/$account/config.php");
        // $url contain my url
        $validate = curl_get($url , $results);
    }
?>
```

book.php

```
<?php
    function book_hotelbeds($results)
    {
        $account = $results['header']['account'];

        include_once("./connector/hot/hotelbeds/account_config/$account/config.php");
        // $url is empty
        $book = curl_get($url , $results);
    }
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
     $url = "http://www.websitelink.com";
?>
```

Comment: no, in validate.php, $url is not empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time you require it, the variables will be introduced.

When you require it again from inside a function, the file has already been required so it is ignored.

The variables are outside the scope of the function at this point, so if you have to you would need to access them by declaring them as `global`.

Perhaps a better idea would be do declare those variables as constants instead, which means they will be available within the function scopes:

```
$myVariable = 'hello';
define('MY_CONSTANT', 'world');

echo 'Global scope: ', $myVariable, MY_CONSTANT, PHP_EOL; // helloworld

function myFunction()
{
    echo 'Function scope: ', $myVariable, MY_CONSTANT, PHP_EOL; // world
}

function myGlobalFunction()
{
    global $myVariable;
    echo 'Function scope using global: ', $myVariable, MY_CONSTANT, PHP_EOL; // helloworld
}
```

[Example.](https://eval.in/532964)

Answer (score 0):

Put your `include_once("./connector/hot/hotelbeds/account_config/$account/config.php");` into index instead. Then if you wanted to use the var `$url` you would need a line above stating that you want that global var: `global $url;`.

Also I suggest changing `$url` name and change it to constant like: `const API_URL = 'website_url'`

Answer (score 0):

Functions `require_once` and `include_once` include file only on time for one call of script. Because you include files **book.php** and **validate.php** in **index.php** then PHP include **config.php** only one time.

You can include **config.php** in **index.php** and use `global` directive inside your function.

Or you can just use functions `include` and `require`. These functions include one file to script many times - on each call.